# What are the differences between different client running modes of ESB

Tags: wso2, esb

I am running some ESB samples available at [1]. [2] states different client running modes such as Smart Client Mode, Gateway/ Dumb Client Mode, Proxy Client Mode, etc..
What are the differences between these client modes?

1. http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB470/Samples
2. http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB470/ESB+Samples+Setup#ESBSamplesSetup-StockQuoteClient

Answer (score 2):

The three mode of running stockquote client can be explained as below.

**Smart Client Mode:**

In this mode you can specify the ESB proxy to be called by the client for mediation before send request to the final end point. You will use it when you need some mediation done in the ESB and then you want request to be send to the end point which you specified.

For example,

```
ant stockquote -Daddurl=http://localhost:9000/services/SimpleStockQuoteService -Dtrpurl=http://localhost:8280/services/StockQuoteProxy1 -Dsymbol=SUN
```

trpurl : This is the ESB proxy to be called by the client , where needs some mediation to be done before calling the ulimate end point (addurl)

addurl : This is what called by the  ESB after doing the mediation.

**Gateway / Dumb Client Mode:**

In this way , client is not knowing where the final request will be delivered after the mediation inside the ESB, so ESB can make 
dynamic decison on the end point where it is mentioned inside the ESB proxy.You can define the endpoint inside ESB as you wish in your own logic using "endpoint" tag. You will use this when you want ESB logic to decide final message delivery point based on the logic inside the ESB proxy.

```
ant stockquote -Dtrpurl=http://localhost:8280/services/StockQuoteProxy1 -Dsymbol=SUN
```

**Proxy Client Mode:**

You will see exactly the same behavior as per the previous example when you run this scenario. 
However, this time the difference is at the client, as it sends the message to the WS-Addressing 
"To" address http://:9000/services/SimpleStockQuoteService, but the transport specifies ESB as the HTTP Proxy. So you will use this when you want ESB to work as pass through proxy and no need any mediation inside, just forward request to the given endpoint in "To" address in WS-Addressing.

```
ant stockquote -Dprxurl=http://localhost:8280/  -Daddurl=http://localhost:9000/services/SimpleStockQuoteService
```

NOTE: addurl is optional here, add it here ,so client will add it to WS-Addressing "To" tag